# pythonのsuper()の使い方

Tags: python, python3

Pythonでsuper()という親クラスからメンバ変数を継承する事ができる関数があると思うのですが、使用方法が理解できません。

以下のコードを例にオブジェクト指向について勉強しています。

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, data):
        # jsonの値(辞書形式)を受け取ります。

        # エンドポイントです。
        self.endpoint = "https://api.gotinder.com/"

        # Tinderのサーバーの内部で使われていると思われる、ユーザー識別子です。
        self.id = data["_id"]

        # 渡されたデータそのものです。
        self.data = data

        # プロフィール文です。プロフィールが空の場合フィールド自体が存在しない???
        if "bio" in data:
            self.bio = data["bio"]
        else:
            self.bio = ""

        # 誕生日をもとに年齢を計算しています。こちらも人によってはフィールド自体が存在しません。
        if "birth_date" in data:
            birth_date = data["birth_date"]
            birth_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                birth_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
            today = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.age = today.year - birth_date.year - \
                ((today.month, today.day) < (birth_date.month, birth_date.day))
        else:
            self.age = None

        # 性別です。男性が0, 女性が1で表されています。
        self.gender = data["gender"]

        # 名前です。
        self.name = data["name"]

        # 写真とloop videoです。サーバーからurlが送られてきます。
        # サーバーからの返り値には、オリジナルのサイズの他に様々な大きさの画像のurlが含まれていますが、正直不要なのでオリジナルの画像のurlだけを格納します。
        self.photos = []
        self.videos = []

        if "photos" in data:
            for photo in data["photos"]:
                self.photos.append(photo["url"])
                if "processedVideos" in photo:
                    self.videos.append(photo["processedVideos"][0]["url"])

        # 仕事です。空だとフィールド自体が存在しないようです。
        self.jobs = []
        if "jobs" in data:
            for job in data["jobs"]:
                if "title" in job:
                    self.jobs.append(job["title"]["name"])
                if "company" in job:
                    self.jobs.append(job["company"]["name"])

        # 学校です。空だとフィールド自体が存在しないようです。
        self.schools = []
        if "schools" in data:
            for school in data["schools"]:
                self.schools.append(school["name"])

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    # 実際にサーバーにリクエストを投げる関数です。
    # headerは後ほど継承先で作成します。
    def _request(self, endpoint, method="GET", params=None):
        url = "https://api.gotinder.com/" + endpoint
        with requests.Session() as s:
            s.headers.update(self.header)
            if method == "GET":
                response = s.get(url, params=params)
            elif method == "POST":
                response = s.post(url, data=json.dumps(params))
            elif method == "DELETE":
                response = s.delete(url, data=json.dumps(params))
            content = response.content
            if len(content) > 0:
                content = content.decode("utf-8")
                content = json.loads(content)

            return content


class API(Person):
    def __init__(self, FBtoken):
        # Facebookのトークンを元に、tinderのトークンを取得します。
        params = {"token": FBtoken}
        with requests.Session() as s:
            headers = {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
            s.headers.update(headers)
            response = s.post(
                "https://api.gotinder.com/v2/auth/login/facebook", data=json.dumps(params))
            if response.status_code == 401:  # 予期せぬトラブル
                sys.exit(1)
            data = json.loads(response.text)["data"]
            self.id = data["_id"]
            self.api_token = data["api_token"]
            self.refresh_token = data["refresh_token"]

        # Tinderのサーバーにリクエストするためのヘッダー。
        self.header = {"X-Auth-Token": self.api_token, "Content-type": "application/json",
                       "User-agent": "Tinder/10.1.0 (iPhone; iOS 12.1; Scale/2.00)"}

        # 自分の情報を取得します。
        # init関数の中にありメソッドが読み込まれたのちに実行される。
        meta = self.getMeta()

        # Personクラスを継承
        super().__init__(meta["user"])

        self.age_filter_max = meta["user"]["age_filter_max"]
        self.age_filter_min = meta["user"]["age_filter_min"]
        self.distance_filter = meta["user"]["distance_filter"]
        self.gender_filter = meta["user"]["gender_filter"]
        self.full_name = meta["user"]["full_name"]

    # 自分の情報を取得
    def getMeta(self):
        endpoint = "meta"
        return self._request(endpoint)

    # 周囲のユーザーを取得
    def getNearbyUsers(self, limit=10):
        endpoint = "user/recs"
        params = {"limit": limit}
        while True:
            results = self._request(endpoint, method="POST",
                                    params=params)["results"]
            if len(results) == 0:
                break

            for result in results:
                yield User(result, self.header)

    # idを指定するとそのユーザーを取得
    def getUser(self, id):
        endpoint = "user/{}".format(id)
        return User(self._request(endpoint, method="GET")["results"], self.header)

    # 自身のプロフィールを更新。正直アプリからやったほうが早くて楽。
    def setProfile(self, Gender=None, age_filter_min=None, age_filter_max=None, distance_filter=None):
        endpoint = "profile"
        params = {}
        if Gender:
            params["Gender"] = Gender  # 0:Male 1:Female
        if age_filter_min:
            params["age_filter_min"] = age_filter_min
        if age_filter_max:
            params["age_filter_max"] = age_filter_max
        if distance_filter:
            params["distance_filter"] = distance_filter

        return self._request(endpoint, params=params, method="POST")

    # 自身の位置情報を更新
    def setLocation(self, latitude, longitude):
        endpoint = "v2/meta"
        params = {"lat": latitude, "lon": longitude}
        return self._request(endpoint, method="POST", params=params)

    # マッチに関する情報と、その他よくわからない情報が格納されている
    def _updates(self, last=0):
        endpoint = "updates"
        params = {"last_activity_date": last}
        return self._request(endpoint, method="POST", params=params)

    # 上で取得した情報からマッチに関する情報だけを抜き出している
    def getMatch(self, last=0):
        results = self._updates(last)["matches"]
        return [Match(result, self.header) for result in results if "person" in result]

    # 残り右スワイプ数
    def getLikesRemaining(self):
        return int(self.getMeta()["rating"]["likes_remaining"])


class User(Person):
    def __init__(self, data, header):
        # Personクラスでリクエストを投げるために、何らかの形でヘッダーを渡さなければなりません。
        # もう少し賢く実装できないかなぁ...。
        super().__init__(data)
        self.header = header

        # 自分との距離です。
        if "distance_mi" in data:
            self.distance_mi = data["distance_mi"]
        else:
            self.distance_mi = None

        # s_number。サーバーから意味ありげに送られてきますが、なんのデータなのかさっぱりわかりません。一応保持。
        if "s_number" in data:
            self.s_number = data["s_number"]
        else:
            self.s_number = None

        # なんとなく変数名から予測がつかないこともないデータ達です。性質をしっかり検証するには課金した女性のアカウントを実験用に作成する必要がありそうなので、適当です。
        if "is_traveling" in data:
            self.is_traveling = data["is_traveling"]
        else:
            self.is_traveling = None
        if "is_tinder_u" in data:
            self.is_tinder_u = data["is_tinder_u"]
        else:
            self.is_tinder_u = None
        if "hide_age" in data:
            self.hide_age = data["hide_age"]
        else:
            self.hide_age = None
        if self.hide_age:
            self.age = None
        if "hide_distance" in data:
            self.hide_distance = data["hide_distance"]
        else:
            self.hide_distance = None
        if self.hide_distance:
            self.distance_mi = None

    # 右スワイプ
    def like(self):
        endpoint = "like/{}".format(self.id)
        return self._request(endpoint)

    #左スワイプ //passは予約語
    def nope(self):
        endpoint = "pass/{}".format(self.id)
        return self._request(endpoint)

    # スーパーライク。動かない??
    def superlike(self):
        endpoint = "like/{}/super".format(self.id)
        return self._request(endpoint, method="POST")


class Match(Person):
    def __init__(self, json, header):

        try:
            self.matchId = json["_id"]
            json.update(copy.deepcopy(json["person"]))
            super().__init__(json)
            self.header = header
            self.message_count = json["message_count"]
            if "messages" in json:
                self.messages = [Message(i) for i in json["messages"]]
            else:
                self.messages = []
        # なんかよくわからないゴミ?データがレスポンスに含まれている模様。とりあえずスルー。
        except KeyError:
            self.header = header
            pass

    #メッセージを送信
    def _sendMessage(self, message):
        endpoint = "user/matches/{0}".format(self.matchId)
        params = {"message": message}
        return self._request(endpoint, method="POST", params=params)


    def sendMessage(self, message):
        if type(message) is str:
            return self._sendMessage(message)
        elif type(message) is list:
            retval=[]
            for m in message:
                retval.append(self._sendMessage(m))
            return retval



class Message:
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.id = json["_id"]
        self.match_id = json["match_id"]
        self.message = json["message"]
        self.timestamp = json["timestamp"]
        self.to = json["to"]
        self.from_ = json["from"]  # fromは予約語

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.message
```

ここにはPersonクラス（親）、APIクラス（子）、Userクラス（子）、Matchクラス（子）と親クラスの子クラスとして3種類あり、API、Userクラスで使用されるsuper()関数が私の理解と違い使用の方法をされている気がします。

APIクラスに記述されているもの：`super().__init__(meta["user"])`
この関数は親クラスからメンバ変数を継承するものだと考えているのですが、meta["user"]というメンバ変数は親クラスに記述されていないです。なのになぜここで継承されているのでしょうか？

Userクラスに記述されているもの：`super().__init__(data)`とあるのですが、これは親クラスにあるdataを継承しているとわかるのですが、その上の行にdef **init**(self, data, header):とあります。これはまずdata、headerが初期化されて、その次に親クラスから継承されたdataがここに上書きされると考えています。この使用方法が私が理解する使用方法なのですが、superには他に違う使い方があるのでしょうか？

もう一つheaderもどこからか継承されていると思うのですが、なぜsuper（）を使用していないのか？

おそらくAPIクラスのイニシャライザに記述されている。

```
self.header = {"X-Auth-Token": self.api_token, "Content-type": "application/json",
                       "User-agent": "Tinder/10.1.0 (iPhone; iOS 12.1; Scale/2.00)"}
```

これが継承されている気がするのですが、そこから継承しているというような記述は見当たらないです。

Comment: 「継承している」のと関数のパラメータがクラス変数と関係があるというのが誤解では？[Python の super() 関数の使い方](https://www.lifewithpython.com/2014/01/python-super-function.html), [super().__init__()が何しているのか分からない](https://teratail.com/questions/85379)

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。つまり名前がmeta["user"]であろうとこの場合、中身はapiクラスのdataが入るという事でしょうか？

Comment: ソースを見ると、直前のgetMeta()で"meta"というendpointから取得したデータのうち"user"に関連するものを基に、自分自身のPersonクラスオブジェクトとしての部分を初期化している、という風に考えられるのでは？

Comment: 理解が追いついていないと思うのですが、イメージとしてはPersonクラスのメンバ変数を再利用してmeta["user"]を追加して使用するという事でしょうか？

Comment: 「メンバ変数を再利用」と「meta["user"]を追加」というのが誤解でしょう。「Personクラスのメンバ変数」を「meta["user"]のデータで書き換える」が近いと思われます。

Comment: そのPersonクラスに記述されたメンバ変数という事はself.endpoint、self.id、self.data〜self.videosまでの事を指しこれらの中身をmeta["user"]で書き換えるという事でしょうか？

Comment: endpointは固定文字列のようなので、それ以外のものが、meta["user"]の内容に応じて書き換えられるのでしょう。

Comment: meta["user"]というのはPersonクラスで言うdataと関連すると考えて良いのでしょうか？

Comment: ソース上では、そのまま代入されているようなので、そうでしょうね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

super()は属性を継承する関数ではありません。親または兄弟クラスにメソッドの呼び出しを委譲するためのものです。
サンプルコードのように、A←B←Cと継承されている場合、
通常メソッドの呼び出しは、まずメソッドをCから探し、見つからなければBから、さらに見つからなければAから、それでも見つからなければAttributeErrorを送出します。
super関数はこの探し始める場所を指定することができるのです。

```
class A:
    def print_name(self):
        print("A")


class B(A):
    def print_name(self):
        print("B")


class C(B):
    def print_name(self):
        print("C")


c = C()
c.print_name()  # print C
# Cより上、つまりBからメソッドを探し始める。
# 見つかったら、superの2つ目の引数にメソッドを束縛する（print_nameメソッドのself引数に入るということ）
super(C, c).print_name()  # print B
# Aからメソッドを探し始める。
super(B, c).print_name()  # print A
```

Comment: 上記のようにもsuper()関数を使用できると知らず、シンプルなコードでとても分かりやすい説明になっている感じがします。しかし、私の理解が乏しいので合っているのか確認したいのですが、上記の場合(質問内のコード)はinitメソッドを呼び出す場所をUserクラスより上のPersonクラスから呼び出すという事でしょうか？その場合、Userクラスのinitメソッドは実行されないのでしょうか？self.header = headerはどのタイミングで実行されるのでしょうか？

Comment: 該当コードのUserクラスのインスタンスを作成した場合、まずUserクラスの__init__メソッドがコールされます。そのメソッドの中でsuper関数を使って親クラス（この場合はPerson）の__init__メソッドをコールしているという流れです。Person.__init__が終わってからself.header = header以降が実行されます。このへんの流れはステップ実行できるIDEなどで実行順序を見るとわかりやすいかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうござます。一度Userクラスのinitから抜けてPeroson init を実行したのちUser initへ戻ってくるという感じでしょうか？クラスは実行の流れを掴むのが難しく、未だにクラスを使用してプログラムを組めないのでこの解説は有難いです。